# Create Custom Form list for sharePoint using managed code

Tags: c#, forms, sharepoint, infopath

I have a sharePoint site, and a list in that site. I want to create a form for populating that list, but I want to be able to make it from code, and then publish it to the site. 
I tried creating in InfoPath a new Blank form and I was able to go in Developer tab and write code for it, but I can't link it to an existing list on the site. 
I also tried to create a new list form in InfoPath, but then the Developer tab is hidden and I can't write code for it.

Is it possible to link that blank form to an existing list on the site? 
If no, how can I create a list form and be able to edit the code using VS?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a blank InfoPath form and add code to it.  Inside the code you can write the logic to read/write from list. Such a form cannot be directly publised to list. It will be an administrator enabled form which has to be deployed via the Central Admin. This form can be added to the Infopath form web part in the list form.